# AutoHotKey determination of the image search location

Tags: image, autohotkey

the script currently works fine ... but can you append the area (xy) in which image will appear? so that he would not look around the screen?

```html
Loop
{
  
  ImageSearch ,,, 0 , 0 , A_ScreenWidth , A_ScreenHeight , mor.png
    bT := ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
  ImageSearch ,,, 0 , 0 , A_ScreenWidth , A_ScreenHeight , 2osoby.png
    bT := ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
ImageSearch ,,, 0 , 0 , A_ScreenWidth , A_ScreenHeight , smiec.png
    bT := ErrorLevel ? bT : 1


        If bT
    {
        bT := 0
        send {PrintScreen}
        Random, x, 1190,1300
        Random, y, 410, 450
       MouseMove, %x%, %y%, 0
Click
        Sleep , 500
}   }
Return
f1::ExitApp
`::Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

From the AHK documentation https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm

> ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, ImageFile
>
> **X1,Y1** The X and Y coordinates of the upper left corner of the rectangle to search, which can be expressions. Coordinates are
>   relative to the active window unless CoordMode was used to change
>   that.

Comment: where i must put this??
x535 y304
x1033 y471

Comment: `ImageSearch ,,, 535, 471 , 1033 , 471 , mor.png`